# I'm confused about Links in Blender

Tags: linked-data

I've got 1 scene for rigging characters & animation cycles, and 2 scenes for different settings, but the character I want to use has to be in both scenes. How does that work out? I've already animated the character for the 1st scene and I want to do it for the 2nd scene but I'm scared it'd overwrite the 1st scene keyframes. How does it work out and what should I do?

Comment: I think you'd better have the model and its rig into a group in a separate .blend file, and link it (using proxies of the group) into your scenes .blend file. This way, making a new proxy won't overwrite animations of the original model's rig.